# Cumulative monthly totals for different tabs on excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, tabs

We have a spreadsheet with 12 months.  Every month has to take the cumulative total of the previous month and add it to the current month.  The columns go as far as "KK" and there are a hundred odd rows.

We don't want to rewrite the formula every month-is this where VBA coding or macros come in? As I have zero experience with those.

Please assist? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hard to help when we have no idea what your setup and expected result are. Please take the time to [read this](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You need to follow the carry forward method, a well known process in commerce & trading.

Answer (score 1):

*This method help you to carry forward Cumulative Sum across sheets.*

[image]

- Apply Cumulative Sum formula in Cell `B3`, `=SUM(A$3:A3)` & fill down.
- Put Caption `Balance`in cell `C7`.

---

[image]

- Array (CSE) formula in Cell `B2`.

`{=INDEX(JAN!$B$3:$B$7,MATCH("Balance",JAN!$C$3:$C$7),1)}`

*Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.*

- Put Cumulative Sum formula in Cell `B3` & fill down.

`=$B$2+SUM(A$3:A3)`

---

[image]

- Repeat above shown steps for rest of the Sheets.
- You may also, *Copy* & *Paste* carry forward array formula across Sheets.

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

**N.B.** Identical data set across sheets, executes entire operation successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Macros and the use of VBA are not required.

So, you have 12 tabs:

- JAN
- FEB
- MAR
- APR
- MAY
- JUN
- JUL
- AUG
- SEP
- OCT
- NOV
- DEC

Each tab's worksheet has many rows and columns, and some of them depend on the prior month's sheet. DEC pulls data from NOV, NOV pulls data from OCT, OCT pulls data from SEP, and so forth. These are known as *links* or *external references*.

Let's say you are in the DEC worksheet and you need to add in data from the NOV worksheet. To reference a cell from another worksheet in the same workbook (file), put the worksheet name followed by an exclamation mark (**!**) before the cell address. For example, to refer to cell **G1** in **NOV**, you type `NOV!G1`.